# Why typing long string into read input with color misbehaves?

Tags: bash, colors, read

I can't seem to move my cursor to the beginning of colored read input when I'm typing a really long string. This below gif shows exactly that, the cursor just stuck on there and I can't move it to left more.

[image]

However, this doesn't happen if I omit any color from read input.

[image]

Is this a 'feature' that I'm not aware of ? Because my script relies on colored read input, this has bothered me alot. Anyway to fix this behavior ?

A little more info, command used.

```bash
read -ep $'\e[31mFoobar\e[0m: ' foo # Colored
read -ep "Foobar: " foo # Not colored
```

And my bash version, if that's relevant.

```bash
bash --version
GNU bash, version 5.1.16(1)-release (x86_64-pc-linux-gnu)
Copyright (C) 2020 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
License GPLv3+: GNU GPL version 3 or later <http://gnu.org/licenses/gpl.html>
```

Comment: This answers your question: [Bash prompt: using \‌\[ and \‌\] within PROMPT\_COMMAND](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/206200/bash-prompt-using-and-within-prompt-command)

Comment: `\[` and `\]` don't work here. You need `\001` and `\002` respectively: `read -ep $'\001\e[31m\002Foobar\001\e[0m\002: ' foo`